# Translating "If (request), that would be great."

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, condicional

In English, I often use the formula, "*If (request), that would be great.*"

For example:

> - If you could go to the supermarket after work, that would be great.
> - If it's possible for you to finish that project today, that would be great.
> - If you could let me know when you land at the airport, that would be great.

What would be some natural ways to express these sentences in Spanish?

Comment: If you could go ahead and come in on Saturday, that would be great.  Mmmkay?  Oh, and I almost forgot.  I'm going to need to you to come in on Sunday, too.

Comment: Bill Lumberg statements, eh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good general pattern that you'd probably want to use, might be:

> Sería bueno si pudieras `Y`. => *It would be great, if you could `Y`.*

...where `Y` is the requested `action`. (*Note: In some cases, the `Sería bueno` could come
after the `si` clause, but both are equivalent.*)

Examples:

> - Sería bueno si pudieras ir a la tienda despues del trabajo. => *If you could go to the supermarket after work, that would be great.*
> - Sería bueno si pudieras avisarme cuando llegues al areopuerto. => *If you could let me know when you land at the airport, that would be great.*

This pattern can be further generalized by replacing `bueno` with any other `adjective` that could describe the result (e.g. `malo` (*bad*), `triste` (*sad*), etc.) and by making the `si` clause any action in the [imperfect subjunctive](http://www.elearnspanishlanguage.com/grammar/verb/imperfectsubjunctive.html). (See: [If-Then Clauses in Spanish](http://www.elearnspanishlanguage.com/grammar/siclauses-unlikely.html).)

Examples:

> Sería muy triste si ella no quisiera ir contigo. => *It be pretty sad if she didn't want to go with you.*

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I would translate the expression to

> Si (petición), sería grandioso.

or

> Si (petición), sería fantástico.